# ORACLE doesn't save time of date. Why?

Tags: oracle, date, time, insert

I'm trying to insert date and time in oracle using this query:

```
insert into table_name
(date_field)
values
(to_date('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

But if I check the entry the date is

```
SUNDAY 03 MAY 2003 00:00:00 CEST
```

The date is correct but the time is wrong. Why?

This appens in all my tables of Oracle.

Comment: How are you "checking the entry"?

Comment: @JustinCave: I simply do a double click on the date value of the entry (using ORACLE SQL Developer)

Comment: Is it actually a timestamp rather than a date - otherwise where is the CEST coming from? Not that it would make any more sense. What are your NLS settings in SQL Developer? Maybe you're using an old version with a display bug, which you could verify by querying in SQL*Plus instead.

Comment: This seems more likely to be user error (or at least confusion) rather than an actual issue with the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it is ok.

Check by formatting result

```
SELECT to_char(date_field,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') date_field FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Thanks @BlueConga. Reading your hint I resolved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

If we insert a date with a time element Oracle will retain the time element.  The default Oracle date format is DD-MON-YYYY (or -YY) which doesn't show the time, but the time is there.

However, you are using a client which is including the time element in its display format, but it is showing as midnight.  Rest assured, that is *not normal Oracle behaviour* .  This is normal Oracle behaviour:

```
SQL> insert into table_name
(date_field)
values
(to_date('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))  2    3    4  
  5  /

1 row created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
  2  /

Session altered.

SQL> select * from table_name
  2  /

DATE_FIELD
--------------------
03-MAY-2003 21:02:44

SQL>
```

Possible explanations for your situation:

1. You are mistaken and you are not really including the time part.
2. You are selecting the wrong row in the client, and not seeing the row you inserted.
3. Your have table has a before/after insert trigger which executes `:new.date_field := trunc(:new.date_field);`.  Although I agree it seems mysterious that all your tables have this trigger which you don't know about.
4. <s>Red Lectroids are stealing the time element and smuggling it back to the 7th Dimension</s>.

Answer (score 0):

The default dateformat of sql developer is without time component. Change your settings User Properties | Database | NLS (I dont know the real englisch menu entries) or issue the query as BlueConga wrote.